# Setting up a single Zookeeper instance and the binding fails

Tags: apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I am trying to set up a single zookeeper instance using the configuration below , however the start log indicates that the zookeeper is halting while trying to bind the port 2181.Can some one please let me know the issue here. Thank you.

**Start up Log;**

```
    2014-07-18 16:00:48,976 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@103] - Reading configuration from: /opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2014-07-18 16:00:48,980 [myid:] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerConfig@289] - Invalid configuration, only one server specified (ignoring)
2014-07-18 16:00:48,982 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@78] - autopurge.snapRetainCount set to 3
2014-07-18 16:00:48,982 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@79] - autopurge.purgeInterval set to 0
2014-07-18 16:00:48,983 [myid:] - INFO  [main:DatadirCleanupManager@101] - Purge task is not scheduled.
2014-07-18 16:00:48,983 [myid:] - WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@113] - Either no config or no quorum defined in config, running  in standalone mode
2014-07-18 16:00:48,997 [myid:] - INFO  [main:QuorumPeerConfig@103] - Reading configuration from: /opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
2014-07-18 16:00:48,998 [myid:] - **ERROR** [main:QuorumPeerConfig@289] - Invalid configuration, only one server specified (ignoring)
2014-07-18 16:00:48,998 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServerMain@95] - Starting server
2014-07-18 16:00:49,007 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.6-1569965, built on 02/20/2014 09:09 GMT
2014-07-18 16:00:49,007 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:host.name=<NA>
2014-07-18 16:00:49,007 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.version=1.7.0_51
2014-07-18 16:00:49,007 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
2014-07-18 16:00:49,007 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.home=/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_51/jre
2014-07-18 16:00:49,007 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.class.path=/opt/zookeeper/bin/../build/classes:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../build/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/netty-3.7.0.Final.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/log4j-1.2.16.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../lib/jline-0.9.94.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../zookeeper-3.4.6.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../src/java/lib/*.jar:/opt/zookeeper/bin/../conf:
2014-07-18 16:00:49,008 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
2014-07-18 16:00:49,010 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
2014-07-18 16:00:49,010 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:java.compiler=<NA>
2014-07-18 16:00:49,010 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.name=Linux
2014-07-18 16:00:49,010 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.arch=amd64
2014-07-18 16:00:49,011 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:os.version=3.10.0-123.4.2.el7.x86_64
2014-07-18 16:00:49,011 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.name=root
2014-07-18 16:00:49,011 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.home=/root
2014-07-18 16:00:49,011 [myid:] - INFO  [main:Environment@100] - Server environment:user.dir=/opt/zookeeper/bin
2014-07-18 16:00:49,018 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@755] - tickTime set to 2000
2014-07-18 16:00:49,018 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@764] - minSessionTimeout set to -1
2014-07-18 16:00:49,018 [myid:] - INFO  [main:ZooKeeperServer@773] - maxSessionTimeout set to -1
2014-07-18 16:00:49,029 [myid:] - INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@94] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
```

**Zookeeper Config File.**

```
    # The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=10
# The number of ticks that can pass between
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=5
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just
# example sakes.
dataDir=/opt/zookeeper/data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
#log directory.
dataLogDir=/opt/zookeeper/log

server.1=localhost:2888:3888

# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
#maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
#autopurge.purgeInterval=1
```

Comment: I had the same issue when I was trying to configure 3 node ZK cluster on the same machine. I configured the same client port for all three instances which was causing this issue. Then I tried only one node cluster and still seeing the same issue. Apparently, there was a stale process that was listening on port 2181 that was causing this issue. Can you check if that is the case with you too?

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to remove the following line from your configuration file

```
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
```

and then restart the server.

Comment: any specific reason to remove that? In my case I have `server.0=localhost:2888:3888`

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS you can edit the following file and add the line for _JAVA_OPTIONS

```
sudo vim /etc/default/zookeeper
```

**export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"**

Then restart process

```
sudo service zookeeper-server restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a standalone zookeeper for test/dev, comment this line in `zoo.cfg`: `#server.1=localhost:2888:3888`

Then, instead of:

> **ERROR** [main:QuorumPeerConfig@289] - Invalid configuration, only one server specified (ignoring)

You will see:

> WARN  [main:QuorumPeerMain@125] - Either no config or no quorum
> defined in config, running  in standalone mode

[Reference](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/zookeeperStarted.html):

> server.1=zoo1:2888:3888
> server.2=zoo2:2888:3888
> server.3=zoo3:2888:3888
>
> The entries of the form server.X list the servers that make up the
> ZooKeeper service. When the server starts up, it knows which server it
> is by looking for the file myid in the data directory. That file has
> the contains the server number, in ASCII.
>
> Finally, note the two port numbers after each server name: " 2888" and
> "3888". Peers use the former port to connect to other peers. Such a
> connection is necessary so that peers can communicate, for example, to
> agree upon the order of updates. More specifically, a ZooKeeper server
> uses this port to connect followers to the leader. When a new leader
> arises, a follower opens a TCP connection to the leader using this
> port. Because the default leader election also uses TCP, we currently
> require another port for leader election. This is the second port in
> the server entry.

Answer (score 0):

my configuration file (zoo.cfg) in single mode is here and its work correctly:

```
# The number of milliseconds of each tick
tickTime=2000
# The number of ticks that the initial 
# synchronization phase can take
initLimit=5
# The number of ticks that can pass between 
# sending a request and getting an acknowledgement
syncLimit=2
# the directory where the snapshot is stored.
# do not use /tmp for storage, /tmp here is just 
# example sakes.
dataDir=/usr/local/zookeeper/data
# the port at which the clients will connect
clientPort=2181
admin.serverPort=8081
4lw.commands.whitelist=*
# the maximum number of client connections.
# increase this if you need to handle more clients
#maxClientCnxns=60
#
# Be sure to read the maintenance section of the 
# administrator guide before turning on autopurge.
#
# http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current  /zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_maintenance
#
# The number of snapshots to retain in dataDir
#autopurge.snapRetainCount=3
# Purge task interval in hours
# Set to "0" to disable auto purge feature
#autopurge.purgeInterval=1

## Metrics Providers
#
# https://prometheus.io Metrics Exporter
#metricsProvider.className=org.apache.zookeeper.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusMetricsProvider
#metricsProvider.httpPort=7000
#metricsProvider.exportJvmInfo=true
```

Answer (score -1):

I would to mention that when you get the following logging message it means the server is actually started.

```
INFO  [main:NIOServerCnxnFactory@94] - binding to port 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181
```

Also the ERROR message that you see if you have a single zookeeper instance as below is actually a warning rather than an error.

```
2014-07-18 16:00:48,980 [myid:] - ERROR [main:QuorumPeerConfig@289] - Invalid configuration, only one server specified (ignoring)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding this to the zoo.cfg
`quorumListenOnAllIPs=true`

Comment: How does this solve the problem? Please elaborate.

Answer (score -3):

Are you running zookeeper it on Windows 64 bit. I was having the same problem but then figured out that Win64 is not supported. See the Zookeeper link http://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.4.5/zookeeperAdmin.html#sc_supportedPlatforms